# json file (lottie animation )

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to load lottie files into the site as html. I removed this code from the [www.lordicon.com](http://www.lordicon.com) site, which puts the lottie files in the subdomain of the site and loads them into the main domain. I have no problem here, but I want to know if you can help me. How lottie files are loaded into the class whose site name is. Thank you very much for your help.

```
<script src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/libs/mssddfmo/lord-icon-2.1.0.js"></script>
<lord-icon
    src="https://cdn.lordicon.com/hrqwmuhr.json"
    trigger="loop"
    colors="primary:#121331,secondary:#08a88a"
    style="width:250px;height:250px">
</lord-icon>
```

Comment: [`Parse the JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and then [iterate over it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but well, what can I do next after I parse the file? Can you explain more?

Comment: Did you read any of the extensive documentation on the lordicon website?

Comment: Not what documents on which subject

Comment: https://lordicon.com/help/32-web-lordicon-custom-element